# Python Regex for string matching

Tags: python, regex

There are 2 rules that I am trying to match with `regex`. I've tried testing on various cases, giving me unwanted results.

Rules are as follows:

1. Find all strings that are numbers (integer, decimal, and negative values included)
2. Find all strings that have no numeric value. This is referring to special characters like !@#$%^&*()

So in my attempt to match these rules, I got this:

```
def rule(word): 
  if re.match("\W", word):
    return True
  elif re.match("[-.\d]", word):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

`Input: output` tests are as follows

`word = '972.2' : True`

`word = '-88.2' : True`

`word = '8fdsf' : True`

`word = '86fdsf' : True` I want this to be False

`word = '&^(' : True`

There were some more tests, but I just wanted to show that one I want to return False. It seems like it's matching just the first character, so I tried changing the regex epressions, but that made things worse.

Comment: For identifying numbers, it is simpler to use `try/except` with  `number=float(string)`

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) says, `re.match` will return a `MatchObject` which always evaluates to `True` whenever the start of the string is matched to the regex.

Thus, you need to use anchors in regex to make sure only whole string match counts, e.g. `[-.\d]$` (note the dollar sign).

EDIT: plus what Max said - use `+` so your regex won't just match a single letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexes (both of them) only look at the first character of your string. Change them to add `+$` at the end in order to make sure your string is *only* made of the target characters.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you need to exclude all except 1 and 2.

Try this:

```
import re

def rule(word):
  return True if re.search("[^\W\d\-\.]+", word) is None else False
```

Results on provided samples:

- 972.2: True
- -88.2: True
- 8fdsf: False
- 86fdsf: False
- &^(: True